# Как настроить в notepad++ выделение текста цветом со своими начальным тегами и конечным тегом?

Tags: xml, notepad++

Для примера

```
<Dialogue condition = "IsAttacking" text = "Не нужно стрелять! Возможно, мы сможем договорится." player = "true" >
```

notepad++ сам подстраивает расцветку под xml, но мне нужно что бы от `text = "` и до `"` выделялось другим цветом.
Как это можно настроить?

Comment: Нагуглил бы сам если бы знал как правильно сформулировать запрос)

Comment: Дополню что бы это можно было изменить в синтаксисе xml, а не создавать новый

Comment: другим цветом по отношению к чему? Текст в кавычках и так другим цветом

Comment: Начиная с text = " и заканчивая " сделать другим цветом, отличным от стандартной xml расцветки

Comment: Там в меню Language в самом низу есть User defined language. Может там получится самостоятельно стиль создать.